# Function does not run in angularjs file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

My code is below from an Angular js file,

```
ctrl.issuesGridConfig = {
        modelSetName: 'issues',
        serializerChildName: 'issues', //will be prepended with "__" before fields for validation
        actions: {
            addRow: {
                active: function(row) {return !ctrl.readOnly;},
                callback: addIssueRow,
            },
            editRow: {
                active: function(issue){ return issue.provider_issue_code;} ? true : false,
                label:  "View test" : "Edit",
                callback: function(issue){
                    $location.path('/issue/' + issue.provider_issue_code);
                }
            },
            deleteRow: {
                active: function(row) {return !ctrl.readOnly;},
                callback: function(row){
                    _.pull(ctrl.activity.issues, row);
                }
            }
        },
```

My problem is- under the **Editrow** I am running the function(issue). it is working fine in **callback:**, but for **active:** it does not work. I get value of **issue.provider_issue_code** under **callback:**, but not under **active:**. I want to make active = true only if issue.provider_issue_code has some value. Please let me know whats going wrong here.

Comment: `function(issue){ return issue.provider_issue_code;} ? true : false` This line doesn't make any sense to me. You're defining a function, then testing if it exists, and if it exists, return true else return false. But it _does_ exist since you're precisely defining it, so `active` will always be true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong code there, active is always true because of your wrong typo, in your code you assign active with a ternary operator: active = condition ? true : false; (the function is the condition there)

```
active: function(issue){ return issue.provider_issue_code;} ? true : false,
```

should be

```
active: function(issue){ return issue.provider_issue_code ? true : false;} ,
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thanks,Yes it was typo. and I didnt got any error while running so was confused what was wrong.